# how to format string to date on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

response field like this:

```
  print(data.openingHours[weekday]);
```

Result is --> **{time: "9.00AM-5.00PM", status: "Open"}**

I tried to format not working:

```
DateFormat("h:mma'-'h:mma").parse(data.openingHours[weekday]['time']);
```

How to format into dateTime?

Comment: You can't parse a date range. Start by splitting the string on `-`, then parse the opening and closing times individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience try this package: [date_format](https://pub.dev/packages/date_format)